# Web API action not found when optional parameter not present in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

please help. 
I had to change routing for Web API to be able to use methods in URL:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // for MVC controllers
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Editions", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        // for Web API
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new  {  id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

I have a controller

```
public class PositionsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JToken Approved()
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for methods with parameters, but I cannot call parameterless method like `http://localhost/API/Positions/Approved`. Instead of calling `Approved` method I got 404 not found error. What I did wrong?

Funny part: Calling URL `http://localhost/API/Positions/Approved/whatever` works. It seems like ID is not so optional as I thought.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this the only route you have defined or are there others before?

Comment: I just built your scenario, and it works fine. You got more stuff going on in your app. More routes, or more stuff in the controller

Comment: Have you happened to put the route into `RouteConfig` instead of `WebApiConfig`? They work slightly different.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Now I edited my question with all route configuration. And yes, it is in RouteConfig. Please, @WeTTTT, could you explain more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the first route (MVC) is being matched instead of the route you actually want.

So for a url like `http://localhost/API/Positions/Approved` the app is looking for a controller called 'APIController' with an action called 'Positions' with a string parameter 'id' which will be set to a value of "Approved".

The quick solution is to change the declaration of your routes so the API route appears before the MVC route, however as previously mentioned I would separate the routes into their respective configs (RouteConfig & WebApiConfig) and ensure that in the Global.asax.cs the routes are registered in the correct order:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Alternatively if you are using WebApi2 you could use Attribute Routing to make things easier.

Comment: YES! That is it! Thanks a lot. Configuration order change did the trick.