# Calling Web API 2.0 action with [Route] attribute with optional parameter returns 404 not found?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Trying to make a parameter **optional** in the Web API 2.0 project using [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) - basically using a question mark syntax to make it optional. But the action is not reachable (404) when the parameter is omitted.

**Call format:**

```
/lists/departments : returns 404
/lists/departments/sometype : works
```

**Action:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("departments/{type?}")]
public List<Department> Departments(string type)
{
    //this action is not being reached
}
```

Changing the order of registering routes in gloabal.asax.cs as shown in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548107/web-api-action-not-found-when-optional-parameter-not-present-in-url) did not help.

**global.asax.cs**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving your type parameter a default value in C# terms. Like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("departments/{type?}")]
public List<Department> Departments(string type = null)
{
    //this action is not being reached
}
```

Comment: that worked. 7 minutes to go before i can accept this as an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation you need to provide a default value for type

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional

"If a route parameter is optional, you must define a default value for the method parameter."

This should work

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("departments/{type?}")]
public List<Department> Departments(string type = null)
{
    //this action is not being reached
}
```